# Azure Function won't start due to missing .NET Framework DLL - "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-4.8

We have an Azure Function which runs on .NET Framework v4.8 (`FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` = `~1` and `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` = `dotnet`). We have a staging instance of this, which runs perfectly well.

And then we have a production instance, to which we publish exactly the same code, but when we call the Function it won't start up due to the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

`System.Runtime.Caching` is referenced due to a referenced project specifying the following path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Runtime.Caching.dll

However, it appears in the .csproj file as:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When I build the project, none of those DLLs are in the \bin folder, and I assume that the target machine is expected to have them in a conventional location.

We are publishing using *Zip deploy* directly from Visual Studio.

Also, I have tried removing the reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\...` and instead referencing via NuGet - this makes no difference.

I then tried setting `Copy Local` = `Yes` for `System.Runtime.Caching`, cleaning, deleting \bin and \obj, then rebuilding and publishing, and then when I trigger the Function...

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)

So why does the staging instance work but exactly the same code on the production instance fails to find the DLL?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Staging</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Supertext.Smartling.AzFunction.csproj.DotSettings" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nito.AsyncEx" Version="5.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="6.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Supertext.Base" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Supertext.Base.NetFramework.Configuration" Version="5.4.0-ci-20210506-142149" />
    <PackageReference Include="Supertext.Base.Security.Cryptography" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="7.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Supertext.AzFunc.Common\Supertext.AzFunc.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Supertext.Smartling.Business\Supertext.Smartling.Business.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Supertext.Smartling.Client\Supertext.Smartling.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Supertext.Smartling\Supertext.Smartling.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I eventually built an entirely new Function App, copy-pasted the config from the original Function App, published the same code from the same running instance of Visual Studio...  and the Function ran without any problems.  :|

Comment: Could you please share your full `.csproj'` file.

Comment: @Harshitha - Project file added.

Comment: Are you getting this error locally or in the deployed app ?

Comment: Only when deployed to the production Function. Not locally, and not when deployed to the staging/testing instance of the Function app.

Comment: What is the Visual Studio Version you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.7.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255095/discussion-between-harshitha-and-awj).

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed an Azure function app by adding the references which you have provided.

I am able to run the function without any issues.

[image]

As per our discussion and as suggested in the comments, create a new Function app and deploy the Function app with the same configurations.

One of the options to clear `dll` version compatibility issues is to add the `assemblyIdentity`  and `bindingRedirect` with the old and new version of the package in the `App.config` (create/add a new App.config file) file as mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/configuring-assembly-binding-redirection).

- Add a new `App.config` file and add the below settings.

[image]

***My `App.config`:***

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Caching" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

> why does the staging instance work but exactly the same code on the production instance fails to find the DLL?

There might be a difference in the framework for both staging and Environment. The app will behave differently based on the environment framework/setup.

Comment: I thought binding redirects were not supported in Azure Functions v1?

Comment: Have you tried it ?

Comment: Yes, and it had no effect.

Comment: Ok..So,for now new app configuration worked for you.Are you facing any issues with the newly created app.

Comment: No more issues. Deleting the previous Azure Function and publishing to an entirely new Azure Function (with exactly the same config) cleared the problem.

Comment: I'm aware of how SO works, but deleting and recreating the Azure Function doesn't feel like a solution to me.